# How to fix Faces Servlet (javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet) not found in web context - cannot configure PrettyFaces DynaView?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, jsf-2, prettyfaces

I currently added the prettyfaces-jsf2-3.3.3.jar to my netbeans project. I also added the  pretty-config.xml in the WEB-INF folder with the following test rewrite rule:

```
<pretty-config xmlns="http://ocpsoft.org/schema/rewrite-config-prettyfaces" 
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://ocpsoft.org/schema/rewrite-config-prettyfaces
                  http://ocpsoft.org/xml/ns/prettyfaces/rewrite-config-prettyfaces.xsd">


<url-mapping id="viewRecipe"> 
    <pattern value="/#{ RecipeBean.filterRecipeName }/" />
    <view-id value="/faces/viewRecipe.jsf" />
</url-mapping>
```

With this configuration the url

```
http://localhost:8080/wie-koche-ich/Spaetzle
//wie-koche-ich is the name of the netbeans project
```

should refer to the viewRecipe.jsf page and set the filterName to Spaetzle. But when I enter the url the glassfish 4.0 server returns a 404 page and the log says "Faces Servlet (javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet) not found in web context - cannot configure PrettyFaces DynaView".

What exactly throws this Exception and how can i fix this?

It seems that the pretty-config.xml wasn't loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This basically means, that PrettyFaces isn't able to find the mapping of the `FacesServlet`. See:

https://github.com/ocpsoft/prettyfaces/blob/3.3.3/core/src/main/java/com/ocpsoft/pretty/faces/config/servlet/WebXmlParser.java#L73

Did you manually define the mapping for the `FacesServlet` in your `web.xml`? If not, you could try to add it. Or you could perhaps try to debug this class to find out what's going on.  Actually this class should (in case of a Servlet 3.x) environment, iterate over all the servlet registrations and find the servlet.

Comment: Thanks after adding     <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping> to the web.xml the Log message disappears, but the Rewrite Rule it self doesn't work, I need to take a closer look on this.

Comment: Ok, feel free to post on the ocpsoft forums if you have any further problems.